# What is the data type of timestamp in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I notice that if my model has a field `expirationTime` of type `DateTime` then I cannot store it iin `timestamp` field in `Cassandra`.

```
QueryBuilder.set("expiration_time",model.expirationTime) //data gets corrupted
```

But if I store time as `milli seconds` then it works.

```
QueryBuilder.set("expiration_time",model.expirationTime.getMillis()) //WORKS
```

Question 1 - Does that mean that the `timestamp` field in `cassandra` is of type `long`? 
Question2 - Is it `cqlsh` which converts the time into readable format like `2018-05-18 03:21+0530`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From DataStax [documentation on CQL types](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html):

> Date and time with millisecond precision, encoded as 8 bytes since epoch. Can be represented as a string, such as 2015-05-03 13:30:54.234.

In Java as input you can use either long with milliseconds, or string literal, supported in CQL, or `java.util.Date` (see the [code](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/3.x/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/TypeCodec.java#L1479)).  When reading, results mapped into `java.util.Date` in driver 3.x/1.x (see [full table for CQL<->Java types mapping](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/#cql-to-java-type-mapping)), or to the `java.time.Instant` in the driver 4.x/2.x (see [CQL<->Java types mapping](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.1/manual/core/#cql-to-java-type-mapping)).

In Python/cqlsh, yes - the data is read as 8-byte long, then is then converted into string representation.

Comment: I do not use Cassandra, but hopefully by now they have updated their API to the modern *java.time* classes that years ago supplanted the terrible legacy class such as `java.util.Date`. If not yet updated, you should immediately convert your `Date` to a `java.time.Instant` object by calling the new [`toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html#toInstant()) method added to the old class. Likewise, you will find a new `from` method on the old class for converting the other direction. Do all your business logic with *java.time* objects. Avoid `Date`